# Most efficient way to do multiple list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, nltk, list-comprehension

Given these three list comprehensions, is there a more efficient way to do this rather than three deliberate sets? I believe that for loops in this case would probably be bad form but if I were to iterate over a large number of lines in rowsaslist I feel like what I have below is not that efficient.

```
cachedStopWords = stopwords.words('english')

rowsaslist = [x.lower() for x in rowsaslist]
rowsaslist = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in rowsaslist]
rowsaslist = [' '.join([word for word in p.split() if word not in cachedStopWords]) for p in rowsaslist]
```

Is combining these all into one comprehension statement more efficient? I know from a readability standpoint it would probably be a mess of code.

Comment: You could use `map()` and `filter()` instead, but same efficiency

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input on this. I'll play around with these suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of iterating 3 times on the same list, you could simply define 2 functions and use them in one single list comprehension:

```
cachedStopWords = stopwords.words('english')


def remove_punctuation(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in text.lower() if c not in string.punctuation)

def remove_stop_words(text):
    return ' '.join([word for word in p.split() if word not in cachedStopWords])

rowsaslist = [remove_stop_words(remove_punctuation(text)) for text in rowsaslist]
```

I've never used `stopwords`. If it returns a list, you'd better convert it to a `set` first to speed up the `word not in cachedStopWords` test.

Finally, the [`NLTK`](http://www.nltk.org/) package might help you process text. See [@alvas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395717/6419007).

Comment: I think there's a better way to deal with the problem than to perform nested loop for removing punctuation and stopwords.

Comment: @alvas: You're right. I've added a link to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the way you currently have it, each list will be *entirely* created before the next one is created. You can get around this by switching from list comprehensions to generator expressions (note the use of `()` instead of `[]`):

```
rowsaslist = (x.lower() for x in rows as list) 
rowsaslist = (''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in rows as list) 
rowsaslist = (' '.join([word for word in p.split() if word not in cachedStopWords]) for p in rowsaslist)
```

Instead of creating lists, this will create 3 generators. Each generator will only produce a value as required, instead of strictly creating each list all at once.

Answer (score 2):

I would favor a functional approach here*

```
' '.join(filter(lambda word: word not in cachedStopWords,
                ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in string.punctuation,
                       map(str.lower, rowsaslist))).split())
```

It's ugly as sin, but there's really no way to make this *not* ugly. Comments are good for these big all-in-one processing jobs.

```
# removes punctuation, filters out stop words, and lowercases
```

That explains everything perfectly.

---

* admittedly that might be because I've been playing around more and more in Haskell!

Comment: Using functions instead of lambdas does help for the readability. No need for comments then.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you need the resulting list to be ordered accordingly as how the input, there are at least two ways to approach this.

First you have two black list that seems you want to remove:

- punctuations
- stop words.

And you want to remove punctuations by looping through the characters, while you want to remove the stopwords by looping through the tokens.

The assumption is that the input is a un-tokenized human readable string.

**Why can't be a punctuation be a token?** That way you can remove the punctuations and stopwords through looping the tokens, i.e.

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> blacklist = set(punctuation).union(set(stopwords.words('english')))
>>> blacklist
set([u'all', u'just', u'being', u'when', u'over', u'through', u'during', u'its', u'before', '$', u'hadn', '(', u'll', u'had', ',', u'should', u'to', u'only', u'does', u'under', u'ours', u'has', '<', '@', u'them', u'his', u'very', u'they', u'not', u'yourselves', u'now', '\\', u'nor', '`', u'd', u'did', u'shan', u'didn', u'these', u'she', u'each', u'where', '|', u'because', u'doing', u'there', u'theirs', u'some', u'we', u'him', u'up', u'are', u'further', u'ourselves', u'out', '#', "'", '+', u'weren', '/', u're', u'won', u'above', u'between', ';', '?', u't', u'be', u'hasn', u'after', u'here', u'shouldn', u'hers', '[', u'by', '_', u'both', u'about', u'couldn', u'of', u'o', u's', u'isn', '{', u'or', u'own', u'into', u'yourself', u'down', u'mightn', u'wasn', u'your', u'he', '"', u'from', u'her', '&', u'aren', '*', u'been', '.', u'few', u'too', u'wouldn', u'then', u'themselves', ':', u'was', u'until', '>', u'himself', u'on', u'with', u'but', u'mustn', u'off', u'herself', u'than', u'those', '^', u'me', u'myself', u'ma', u'this', u'whom', u'will', u'while', u'ain', u'below', u'can', u'were', u'more', u'my', '~', u'and', u've', u'do', u'is', u'in', u'am', u'it', u'doesn', u'an', u'as', u'itself', u'against', u'have', u'our', u'their', u'if', '!', u'again', '%', u'no', ')', u'that', '-', u'same', u'any', u'how', u'other', u'which', u'you', '=', u'needn', u'y', u'haven', u'who', u'what', u'most', u'such', ']', u'why', u'a', u'don', u'for', u'i', u'm', u'having', u'so', u'at', u'the', '}', u'yours', u'once'])
>>> sent = "This is a humanly readable string, that Tina Guo doesn't want to play"
>>> [word for word in word_tokenize(sent) if word not in blacklist]
['This', 'humanly', 'readable', 'string', 'Tina', 'Guo', "n't", 'want', 'play']
```

If you don't need the order of the words to be as of the input, using the `set().difference` function may speed your code up:

```
>>> set(word_tokenize(sent)).difference(blacklist)
set(['humanly', 'play', 'string', 'This', 'readable', 'Guo', 'Tina', "n't", 'want'])
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to tokenize the string, you can use `str.translate` to remove punctuation and that'll surely be more efficient than looping through the characters:

```
>>> sent
"This is a humanly readable string, that Tina Guo doesn't want to play"
>>> sent.translate(None, punctuation)
'This is a humanly readable string that Tina Guo doesnt want to play't
>>> stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
>>> [word for word in sent.translate(None, punctuation).split() if word not in stoplist]
['This', 'humanly', 'readable', 'string', 'Tina', 'Guo', 'doesnt', 'want', 'play']
```